# Im getting a double scrollbar on my website

Tags: html, css

I have been looking around and nothing is fixing my issue, the site is atnva.com, and I am getting a double scrollbar. Be appreciated if you can help, thanks.

Comment: it would help if you showed some code of what you're doing and what you've tried, guessing from scratch seems complicated

Comment: Sorry Gamopo I presumed people would use inspect element, but ill submit so code in a second

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove **height: 100%;** from your style sheet. Tested and working.

```
html,body
{
    font-family:"Josefin Sans";
    background-color: #4a86e8ff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; <-- Remove
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0.5px;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
}
```

You are specifying that the body be 100% of screen height which was forcing the extra scrollbar to appear. Hope this helps.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Looks like you have `overflow-x: hidden` in `<body>` element. Which means that you wanted to hide horizontal scroll as well. Please check the `<body>` and `<footer>`for the paddings, they create the space around elements thus making them wider.

**Update:**
The issue with `height:100%` is important as well and will fix your problem in general, but paddings won't go away and your website template will still suffer if you don't fix it.

[image: Pdding in footer]

I suggest you explore the `box-sizing: border-box` property, you can learn more about it here:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_box-sizing.asp

Answer (score 0):

**Add** to your CSS:

```
html {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the problem is `height: 100%` which you gave to body
because 100% means whole height of your monitor but because of your browser header and windows task bar browser wont be able to give all 100% to body so you should use 100vh which means view height